# How to handle validation of multiple hidden fields

Tags: php, html, laravel, validation

I have created a form where in many cases some fields are **not displayed** until user `select` a certain `option` that will make the particular field **displayed**, this is controlled by HTML onchange Event Attribute with functions in script. To this point everything works fine.

**Problem**:

In the Request class I am implementing some rules for validation , for all **displayed** fields and for particular **none displayed** fields if only their options are selected then they should **be validated**. In my case I have 8 of this **none displayed** fields are `a_text, b_text, c_text, d_text, e_text, f_text,g_text, h_text`. If this fields were 2 it would be easy to write an If statement to choose which should be validated and which should not be validated like  below:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class StoreSectionERequest extends FormRequest

public function rules(Request $request)
{
    $a = $request->a;
    $b = $request->b;
    if($a==5 && $b==3){
        return [
            //for none displayed fields only validate the below
            'a_text' =>'required',
            'b_text' =>'required',
            //..and other displayed fields will be valuated.
        ];
    }elseif(!$a==5 && $b==3){
        return [
             //for none displayed fields only validate the below
            'b_text' =>'required',
            //..and other displayed fields will be valuated.
        ];     
    }elseif($a==5 && !$b==3){
        return [
             //for none displayed fields only validate the below
            'a_text' =>'required',
            //..and other displayed fields will be valuated.
        ];     
    }
     // in case all none displayed field are not selected only check other fields below
    return [
            // validaying all none displyed field here]; }}
```

In my case I have **8** fields which are **none displayed**, of which I have to handle all cases of fields if it's selected and not, this will lead to 100's or a lot of if...elseif..statements. What is the wright approach to handle this kind of task.

Form

```
 <form method="POST" action="{{ route('......') }}">@csrf
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5" id="lackingSkills">
            <label for="">Which skills and competencies graduates are lacking? </label>
            <select name="a" multiple="multiple" id="skills" class="form-control select2 @error('a')
            is-invalid
          @enderror" onchange="myFunction()">
              <option value="1" @if (old('a')=="1" ) {{ 'selected' }} @endif>Information and communication skills</option>
              <option value="2" @if (old('a')=="2" ) {{ 'selected' }} @endif>Interpersonal skill</option>
              <option value="3" @if (old('a')=="3" ) {{ 'selected' }} @endif>System management skills</option>
              <option value="4" @if (old('a')=="4" ) {{ 'selected' }} @endif>Innovation skills</option>
              <option value="5" @if (old('a')=="5" ) {{ 'selected' }} @endif>Others. Specify</option>
            </select>
            <small class="text-primary">If necessary, choose more than one option.</small>
            @error('a') <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6" id="skillReason" {!! $errors->has('a_text') || old('a') == 5 ? '':' style="display: none"' !!} >
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
              <textarea rows="2" class="form-control @error('a_text')@enderror" name="e2_10" id="skillReason" placeholder="Type here.."></textarea>  
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6">
            <select name="b" id="b" class="form-control" onchange="myFunction2()">
              <option value="" selected disabled>Select</option>
              <option value="1" @if (old('b')=="1" ) {{ 'selected' }} @endif>Most of them match the requirements</option>
              <option value="2" @if (old('b')=="2" ) {{ 'selected' }} @endif>Only some match the requirements</option>
              <option value="3" @if (old('b')=="3" ) {{ 'selected' }} @endif>Other, specify</option>
            </select>
            @error('b') <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 mt-2" {!! $errors->has('e3_5') || old('b') == 3 ? '':' style="display: none"' !!} >
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
              <textarea rows="2" class="form-control" id="b_text" name="b_text" placeholder="Type here.."></textarea>
              <label for="floatingInput" id="specify">Specify here..</label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6">
            <select name="c" id="graduatesPreference" class="form-control" onchange="myFunction3()">
              <option value="" selected disabled>Select</option>
              <option value="1" @if (old('c')=="1" ) {{ 'selected' }} @endif>Yes</option>
              <option value="2" @if (old('c')=="2" ) {{ 'selected' }} @endif>No</option>
            </select>
            @error('c') <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6" id="preferenceReason" {!! $errors->has('c_text') || old('c') == 1 ? '':' style="display: none"' !!}>
            <label for="">Provide the reason, why you have a preference for a specific university?</label>
            <textarea name="c_text" id="" rows="3" class="form-control" placeholder="Provide the reason here ..."></textarea>
          </div>
      
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <select name="d" id="qualification" class="form-control @error('d')is-invalid @enderror" onchange="myFunction4()">
              <option value="" selected disabled>Select</option>
              <option value="1" @if (old('d')=="1" ) {{ 'selected' }} @endif>Bachelor’s degree</option>
              <option value="2" @if (old('d')=="2" ) {{ 'selected' }} @endif>Post-graduate</option>
              <option value="3" @if (old('d')=="3" ) {{ 'selected' }} @endif>Other, specify</option>
            </select>
            @error('d') <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12" id="d_text" {!! $errors->has('d_text') || old('d') == 3 ? '':' style="display: none"' !!}>
            <label for="">Explain why?</label>
            <textarea name="d_text" id="d_text" rows="3" class="form-control" placeholder="Provide the reason here ..."></textarea>
          </div>

           ////.............others fields like e,f,g,h, all have the same functionality like the above ones.
         
          <div class="action-button d-flex justify-content-center bg-white pt-2 pb-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
   
<script>
/// various function for onchange
myFunction()
myFunction2()
myFunction3()
myFunction4()
</script>
```

My question: what is the wright approach to handle the above scenario without writing 100's of if..elseif statements. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure if i get it right but you can try "sometimes" or "required_if" or "required_unless" validation rules. "if only their options are selected then they should be validated", this suits "sometimes" rule. here official documentation:

[sometimes][1]
[required_if][2]
[required_unless][3]


 [1]: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#validating-when-present
 [2]: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-required-if
 [3]: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-required-unless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In form validation u have rules like required with or without, u can see more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-required-with)

Little bit lower on the docs u can see [Conditionally Adding Rules](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#conditionally-adding-rules)

So basically u will be doing same validation but without too much mess in your code.

Comment: Thanks @cile, you just saved my project and my days.